Renyi parking problem for finite intervals
The so called Renyi parking constant gives the covering density of an infinite interval $[0,L]_{L\to\infty}$  that was randomly covered by unit intervals. Covering is only allowed if the place is not occupied by a previously covered interval. The process finishes if the largest uncovered segment is shorter than $1$. The covering density $C_\infty$ can be exactly expressed by a double integral
$$C_\infty=\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-2\int_0^x\dfrac{1-e^{-y}}{y}{d}y\right)dx\approx 0.74759792\ldots \;\text{for} \; L \to \infty,\tag{1}$$
i.e. almost $75\%$ are occupied by disjunct unit intervals.
If the interval to be covered is finite then no exact density is known except for the trivial cases
$$\begin{matrix}C=&0 \;&\text{for} \; &L \lt 1\\C=&1/L\; &\text{for} \; &1\le L \le 2\\C=&2/3\; &\text{for} \; &L = 3.\end{matrix}\tag{2}$$
The best density approximation for all other cases I could find is already 60 years old (Dvoretzky1964). It evaluates the expected density to
$$C=L^{-1}\left(C_\infty (L+1)-1\right) +\mathcal{O}\left[L^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2e}{L}\right)^{L-3/2}\right]\;\text{for} \; L \gt 2,L\ne3.\tag{3}$$
Especially for small $L$ this approximation is very inaccurate.
For $L=2.01$ we expect from eq.$(2)$ a density close to $0.5$ but get from eq.$(3)$ $C=0.622+\mathcal{O}\left[0.826\right]$. For $L=3.01$ we expect from eq.$(2)$ a value close to $0.\overline{6}$ and also get from eq.$(3)$ $C=0.664+\mathcal{O}\left[0.811\right]$. But for both examples the error term is larger than the expected value.
Does a better approximation or exact expression for the expected density exist? What is known about the density distribution for $L\gt2,L\ne3$?
Dvoretzky, A.; Robbins, H.; On the Parking Problem, Publ. Math. Inst. Hung. Acad. Sci. 9, 209–224 (1964) (there eq.1.3, free download)

Would some kind of induction (i.e., iterative analysis) help? We have the basic case with $L = 2$ and density $0.5$, and we can divide each case w.r.t. the position of the first interval.

I don't think you know what $\mathcal{O}$ means. The expression $A = B + \mathcal{O}(C)$ does not mean $A \in [B-C,B+C]$. Rather it means $A \in [B-\lambda C, B+ \lambda C]$, where $\lambda > 0$ is an absolute constant (usually $A,B,C$ are functions).

Big $O$ notation.

You can express the expected number of parked cars for any $L$ using the following recursion:
$$
n(L)=\begin{cases}
0 && \text{if } L < 1; \\
1 + \frac{2}{L-1}\int_{0}^{L-1}n(x) dx && \text{if } L \ge 1.
\end{cases}
$$
The recursion relation arises from the fact that parking a car in the interval from $x$ to $x+1$, which can occur for any $x \in [0, L-1]$ with equal probability, leaves two remaining intervals to be filled by cars: one of length $x$, and one of length $L-1-x$.  So
$$
n(x)=1+\frac{1}{L-1}\int_{0}^{L-1}\left(n(x) + n(L-1-x)\right)dx\\=1+\frac{2}{L-1}\int_{0}^{L-1} n(x) dx.
$$
This is going to be continuous, but will have a different functional form for each value of $\lfloor{L}\rfloor$.  E.g., $n_0(x)=0$ is correct for $x\in[0,1]$.  Then
$$
n_1(x)=1+\frac{2}{x-1}\int_{0}^{x-1}n_0(y)dy=1
$$
for $x\in[1,2]$; and
$$
n_2(x)=1+\frac{2}{x-1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}n_0(y)dy + \int_{1}^{x-1}n_1(y)dy \right)=1+\frac{2}{x-1}(0+(x-2))=3-\frac{2}{x-1}
$$
for $x\in[2, 3]$.  This gives you back $n(3)=2$, or $\rho(3)\equiv n(3)/3=2/3$, as stated in the original problem.  To go one step further,
$$
n_3(x) = 1+\frac{2}{x-1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}n_0(y)dy + \int_{1}^{2}n_1(y)dy + \int_{2}^{x-1}n_2(y)dy\right) \\
= 1 + \frac{2}{x-1}\left(0 + 1 + \left(3 - 2\log(y-1)\right)\vert_2^{x-1}\right)
\\
=1+\frac{2}{x-1}\left(1+3(x-3)-2\log(x-2)\right) \\
=7 - \frac{10}{x-1} - \frac{4\log(x-2)}{x-1}.$$
And so
$$
n(4)=7-\frac{10}{3}-\frac{4}{3}\log 2=\frac{11}{3}-\frac{4}{3}\log 2 \approx 2.7425, 
$$
and $\rho(4)\approx 0.6856.$

Could you give a derivation, sketch or a source? For the interval $[2,3)$ you apply $n(3), \rho(3)$ however the interval is open at $3$.

Whether the intervals are open or closed doesn't matter, since the function is continuous... I'll edit it.

The first interval should be $[0,1)$.
